# BizTalk Interface to Copy file from oracle cloud to another destination

Tags: biztalk

Create an interface

Copy Generated file in server in Cloud directory and BizTalk to send file to another location

Comment: BizTalk a VM in the cloud or on premises? What have you tried?  What issues are you having?

Comment: Do i need to use SMTP port to connect to oracle cloud directory?

Comment: No, a SMTP is for sending emails, noting to do with Oracle Cloud directory.

Comment: My bad....i mean SFTP..

Comment: Yes, SFTP would be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SFTP adapter to get the files from the Oracle cloud, and have a send port subscribing to it to send it to your copy location.

If you want BizTalk to leave the original file, you will need to have BizTalk 2016 with CU 6, as earlier version do no have the read-only functionality in the SFTP adapter.  If you don't have this, then you will need a different location in Oracle cloud where BizTalk picks it up from, and two send ports, one that sends it to a different location in Oracle Cloud and the other to the copy location.